# Firebase massaging

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to handle the messaged from FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) in andorid;

This is my code

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("TAG", "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }

                        // Get new FCM registration token
                        String token = task.getResult();

                        // Log and toast
                        Log.d("TAG", token);
                        Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(true);
```

And i have send messaged from firebase console.

But i want to handle the messages.
So i'have did this doc says https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

This is manifest.xml

```
  <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
            
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay" />
        
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                android:resource="@color/white" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </service>
```

This is my FirebaseMessagingService extended class

```
public class MessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MessageService";


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Got it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to resgister this FirebaseMessagingService class to Firebase messaging

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to register the class of your messaging service, you need to register the application itself. It should be google-services.json configuration file in your project with all necessary info about the project in firebase console. It will make kind of connection between your app and project created in Firebase console.

There are several ways to get this configuration file:

1. Generate google-services.json via Firebase console https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#register_your_app_with_firebase
2. Generate it via Android studio. Tools -> Firebase -> Cloud messaging -> complete wizard "Setup Firebase cloud messaging"

Comment: Ok, thankyou, But really i have done a mistake in Manifest.xml file .

Answer (score 0):

You have done a mistake in manifest.xml file.

You had to replace this

```
<service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
            
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay" />
        
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                android:resource="@color/white" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </service>
```

with this

```
<service android:name=".helpers.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".helpers.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

and create these classes

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("TAG", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
    }
}
```

and MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "DEEDDEED";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        // ...

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
              //  scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
              //  handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);

        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Database database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        map.put("user",database.getPhone());
        map.put("token",s);
        Call<Void> call = new Server().getRetrofitInterface().executeUpdatePTK(map);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```